# Why is [ACK] sent after [FIN,ACK] in wireshark packet tracer?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I am using packettracer for the first time to capture and analyze the packets.

I created a Apache2 webserver and created a html webpage and then opened it on browser by hosting this page.

I analyzed the packets but couldn't understand the part related to the packet no. 8 where the client sends a [FIN,ACK] to the server after [ACK] flag is already sent in the previous step.

Why is the ACK flag sent along with FIN when it has already been sent in packet no. 7 ?

--

[image]